# Visual Studio project file adds unwanted dependency and creates a circle

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a project written in Visual Studio 2008 that generates the following linker command line:

```
/OUT:"../Debug IH East\CommonDlgs.dll" 
/INCREMENTAL:NO 
/NOLOGO 
/LIBPATH:"../Debug IH East/Lib" 
/DLL 
/MANIFEST 
/MANIFESTFILE:"Debug IH East\CommonDlgs.dll.intermediate.manifest" 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
/DEBUG 
/PDB:"c:\Users\rdrichardson\OneDrive - Rad-Con\CAPS Builds\trunk\Debug IH East\/CommonDlgs.pdb" 
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS 
/DYNAMICBASE:NO 
/IMPLIB:"c:\Users\rdrichardson\OneDrive - Rad-Con\CAPS Builds\trunk\Debug IH East\/Lib/CommonDlgs.lib" 
/MACHINE:X86 
/ERRORREPORT:PROMPT 
CapsLib.lib CJ60Lib.lib "..\debug ih east\lib\capsdata.lib"
```

I only listed CapsLib.lib and CJ60Lib.lib as dependencies.  CapsData.lib is not listed anywhere in the project configuration that I can find.  Having it in this project creates a circular dependency because CapsData depends on the CommonDlgs project.  I have listed $(OutDir)/Lib as an additional library directory, and $(OutDir) resolves to ..\debug ih east\lib.  Where did CapsData come from and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to have been the solution file.  I noticed that a different configuration also listed a file in the the Debug IH East folder as a linker input, and the Debug IH East folder did not exist when this other configuration was created.  The only thing the two configurations had in common was that they were part of the same solution.  I looked at the project dependencies.  I found that the solution specified that the CommonDlgs project depended on the CapsData project and the CapsLib project but not the CJ60Lib project.  I removed the CapsData dependency and added the CJ60Lib dependency, and the problem went away.